# Email Studio - Extract Data

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to get extract Text-Qualified data in text datatype specific columns but getting Text-Qualified in all columns either it is date, number or boolean datatype.

Can I extract data from data extension (Email Studio) with Text-Qualified only in text datatype columns.

Example:

```
1342872,"114561","7302038","7559843","Test Announcements","abcannouncements@abc.com","2017-05-23 12:42:00","2017-05-23 12:43:00","2017-05-23 12:43:00","MULTIPLE_SEND","Deleted","ABD Newsletter Employees","Test Announcements","ExactTargetSend","","False","Default Commercial","Default Commercial","False","","True","",""
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no options in SFMC to change the text-qualification behavior.